# how to restore a deleted commit from Gerrit gui. I only have the commit link now

Tags: git, gerrit

I deleted a commit from Gerrit gui. I only have the commit link now. But don't know the hash-id to restore it. is there any way to do it?

Comment: You have deleted the code review request from Gerrit GUI?

Comment: Do you mean you deleted a change? In Gerrit is not possible to delete a single commit from the UI. However, it is possible to delete a change. In that case, the commits corresponding to the change are no longer accessible from the UI, but they still exist server side. They will be totally removed on the next Git GC run. Have a look at slide 89 of this presentation: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1C73UgQdzZDw0gzpaEqIC6SPujZJhqamyqO1XOHjH-uk/edit#slide=id.g4d6c16487b_1_2892

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it from within Gerrit (which I don't use), but if you have access to the underlying repository, you can use:

```
git reflog
```

which shows all commits that you passed through. (The commit is still somewhere in the repository, but since there is no reference to it anymore, you cannot easily find/show it). You can visualize the commits using

```
git show <sha-1>
```

If you have identified the one you lost, you can then recover it using `git cherry-pick`, `git checkout`, `git branch` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the log to see the commit hash and reset it.

```
git reflog
git reset --hard <commit sha>
```

after running this you can see the deleted commit in the tree but only if commit is present you can see identify which commit to replace. Hope this helps.